# Why does importing a custom derive Foo via `use some_crate::derive_foo` not work?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-macros

I want to use a custom derive macro that uses attributes. For Rust 2015, I wrote:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate pest_derive;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[grammar = "grammar.pest"]
pub struct MyParser;
```

Using `edition = '2018'`, `extern crate` is deprecated so `macro_use` is unavailable. I assumed I could write `use pest_derive::{grammar,derive_parser};`, but I have to write `use pest_derive::*;`.

How can I avoid the glob import? The code for the pest_derive crate is [very simple](https://github.com/pest-parser/pest/blob/8c8e4a917149d6cc307f07ae06330e6bf816f083/derive/src/lib.rs#L267-L277), I have no idea what necessary thing `*` imports that isn’t `derive_parser` or `grammar`.

```
error[E0658]: The attribute `grammar` is currently unknown to the compiler and
              may have meaning added to it in the future (see issue #29642)
  --> src/parser/mod.rs:10:3
   |
10 | #[grammar = "rst.pest"]
   |   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Pedantically, *deprecated* doesn't mean that you can't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the incorrect syntax for importing the derive. You import the name of the derive, not the underlying function. In this case, `use pest_derive::Parser`:

```
use pest_derive::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[grammar = "grammar.pest"]
pub struct MyParser;
```

or

```
#[derive(pest_derive::Parser)]
#[grammar = "grammar.pest"]
pub struct MyParser;
```

This question isn't specific to Rust 2018, either. Rust 1.30 and up allows you to import macros like this.

Comment: Interesting. I'm sure I imported `pest::Parser` at some point, which should be identical to `pest_derive::Parser`. So you have to import the trait from the crate implementing the derive?

Comment: @flyingsheep *which should be identical to `pest_derive::Parser`* — it is not, no more than `crate1::Parser` is the same as `crate2::Parser`. *import the trait from the crate implementing the derive* — no, you import the derive macro `Parser` from the crate implementing the macro; you probably also have to import the trait `Parser` from the main crate as well.

Comment: Got it! That's a bit confusing if you think in names: “I've already imported a thing called `Parser`, I shouldn't have to do it twice”